# How to get single row from a query involving two tables. 2 Foreign Keys are repeated in one entry of child table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
1. tbl_clubs
2. tbl_match_schedule
```

tbl_club has fields;

```
fld_id | fld_club_name
```

tbl_match_schedule has fields;

```
fld_id | fld_club_id_one | fld_club_id_two | fld_match_time.
```

Now the flow is that admin will 
1. go to the add new match schedule.
2. Select the name of club from drop down 1
3. Select the name of the 2nd club (playing against) from drop down 2
4. Give Match time and save.

Now the problem is that I am unable to select the data properly. I need one row, but it 
gives me two rows when I put the following query

SELECT 
ms.fld_id,  ms.fld_id_club_one , ms.fld_id_club_two , ms.fld_match_time, c.fld_club_name, c.fld_id
 FROM 
 tbl_match_schedule as ms, tbl_club as c
 WHERE 
c.fld_id = ms.fld_id_club_one OR c.fld_id = ms.fld_id_club_two

Please help me, I want something in this form `"club name one"` vs `"club name two"` at `"19:00"`

I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly this should do:

```
SELECT c1.fld_club_name AS 'club_name_one', c2.fld_club_name AS 'club_name_two', s.fld_match_time AS 'at' FROM tbl_match_schedule s
    LEFT JOIN tbl_clubs c1 ON s.fld_club_id_one = c1.fld_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_clubs c2 ON s.fld_club_id_two = c2.fld_id
```

Of course you can add a `WHERE` or `ORDER` clause after this to suit your further needs as long as you use the `c1.` and `c2.` shorthands when you refer to the clubs as the full table name would be ambiguous.